# Getting undefined in react routing properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to send some properties (`loading` and `getContacts`) to a Component in reactjs . I use routes in order to get each path, but the result in the target component is undefined. Whats wrong with it?

```
const App = () => {
  
  const [getContacts , setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [loading , setLoading] = useState(false);
  
  return(
    <div className='App'>
        <Navbar/>
       
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element = {<Navigate to ="/contacts"/>}/>

          <Route path='/contacts' loading= {loading} contacts= {getContacts} element= {<Contacts/>} />

          <Route path="/contacts/add" element = {<AddContact/>}/>

          <Route path = "/contacts/:contactId" element = {<ViewContact/>}/>

          <Route path = "/contacts/edit/:contactId" element = {<EditContact/>}/>

          <Route path="*" element={

              <div className='text-light py-5'>
                Not Found!
              </div>}

          />

        </Routes>

    </div>
);
export default App;
```

In Contact.jsx I have:

```
const Contacts = ({ contacts, loading }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div>{contacts}</div>
            <div>{loading}</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Contacts;
```

But both of them are undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing the state variables directly into the children element :

```
<Route path='/contacts' element={<Contacts loading={loading} contacts={getContacts}/>} />
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the props to your `<Route/>` component.

```
<Route
  path="/contacts"
  loading={loading}
  contacts={getContacts}
  element={<Contacts />}
/>
```

But instead you should pass them to your actual `<Contacts/>` component

```
<Route
  path="/contacts"
  element={<Contacts loading={loading} contacts={getContacts} />}
/>
```